# In Django: How do I auto-fill a ManyToMany-Field on save(), when called from django-admin?

Tags: python, django, model, save

Here's my `Conversation`model:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by')
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

**I want to automatically add a random user into the `participants` property after the conversation is created.**

To do this, first I tried signal-catching, using the `post_save` signal. However, the `participants` would not save correctly, and I also ran into the problem that you have to disable the signal *within* the signal-catching method, to avoid an endless recursion, and it all felt very wrong.

In my second try, I overwrote the `save()`method:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    # first, save normally, so the object exists
    super(Conversation, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)

    # then add some conversationalists
    if self.participants.count() < 2:
        new_participant = User.objects.order_by('?')[:1].get()
        self.participants.add(self.creator)
        self.participants.add(new_participant)
```

Now there are two distinct behaviours, depending on wether I use Django-Admin or the console:

1. when I create a new Conversation object, set its `creator` and call `save()` in the console, everything works as expected.
2. when I create a new Conversation in the admin, set its `creator` and hit the 'Save'-Button, the list of participants is still empty after saving.

My first instinct is that the admin somehow overrides this behaviour. Can this be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in thinking you need to save the Conversation again after adding participants. You don't: a many-to-many field is not really a field on the model, it's an entity in a separate linking table. Just calling `add` is enough to save the new participant.

Comment: You are right. It works the same way when I remove the second call to save(). However, the relationship is still not saved.

Comment: After some further testing, it turns out that it IS saved, but not when I use Django-Admin. -- updating my question.

Comment: marking your answer as correct, since it answered my original question.